# User name instead of user.id in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Quick question: I want to display user name(in my case, an email) instead of user id in view, I write in view this code:

```
<%= User.find(post.user_id).Email %>
```

But do not break I the agreement MVC, and this code should I move to a model?

Comment: You can try `<%=current_user.email%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you cannot use capitalized Email like that - you need to call a method (lowercase) email not the class name.

```
<%= User.find(post.user_id).email %>
```

You probably want to find @user = User.find(@post.user_id) in the controller then you can do @user.email in the view... or even better set @user_email in the controller.  You shouldn't really call models from the view.  Your controller should talk to the model and pass the data to the view.

So, something like this in the controller:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@user_email = @post.user.email
```

then in the view you can just do

```
<%= @user_email %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I write this:
<%= post.user.email %>
instead of:
User.find(post.user_id).email. And will this right way?

Comment: yup - if you're happy having that chain in your view you can do that... most likely it'd be @post.user.email if you set the instance variable

Comment: I've clarified some alternatives in my answer